# In react, how do I do an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I react, have this:

```
return (
   <p title={ 'name' }> TEST </p>
)
```

And I want to do an `if` statement within the `return`. I tested this:

```
return (
   <p title={ 'name' }> TEST </p>
   if (variable) {
      <p> hello </p>
   } else {
      <p> world </p>
   }
)
```

Obviously, I have no idea what I'm doing. What's the correct approach? Sorry about the entry-level question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [ternary operator (`?`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), and you also have to have a wrapper element to contain the two separate paragraphs (title and content), so a simple return would be:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <p title={'name'}> TEST </p>
            <p> { variable ? "hello" : "world" } </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For readability, it's better to split the "one-liner":

```
// ...
<p>
{ 
    variable ? (
        <em style={{color: 'black'}}>hello</em>
    ) : (
        <em>world</em> 
    )
}
</p>
// ...
```

However, it's not always that simple, so I'd recommend using a placeholder variable, e.g.:

```
render() {

    var $content;
    if(variable) {
        $content = (<p>hello</p>);
    }
    else {
        $content = (<p>world</p>);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <p title={'name'}> TEST </p>
            {$content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: But how do I add HTML within it, like `<p> { variable ? "<em>hello</em>" : "world" } </p>`? This currently outputs the `<em>` tags as text...

Comment: Then you'd need to remove the quotes, e.g. `<p>{ variable ? <em>hello</em> : <em>world</em> }</p>`. But this can get out of hand pretty quickly, so if you need to render a complex element consider using a placeholder variable, or better, child components.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use `<p>{ variable ? <em style="color:black">hello</em> : <em>world</em>` because the colon within the style. I will likely end up using placeholder variable but I still want to learn how to do it this was as well. Is it still possible? Like maybe escaping the colon like `\:`

Comment: style attributes in JSX are added as an object. `<em style={{color: "black"}}>hello</em>`

Comment: Thanks for correcting @flight2039! Updated my answer.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Error is use JSX syntax instead of `if-statement`

```
return (
   <>
   <p title={ 'Publish Checklist' }> TEST </p>
    {
        variable ? <p> hello </p>: <p> world </p>
    }
   </>
)
```

Comment: But what is I have a colon within the text, like `<p> hel:lo </p>`. Do I need to escape it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary conditional operator(?)

```
return (
   <p title={ 'Publish Checklist' }> TEST </p>
   {
      variable?<p> hello </p>:<p> world </p>
   }
)
```

Comment: But what is I have a colon within the text, like `<p> hel:lo </p>`. Do I need to escape it?

Comment: <p>{"hel:lo"}</p> ; you can use like this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ternary operator:

```
   {variable ?
      <p style={{ color: 'black'}}> Hello</p> 
   :
      <p> world </p>
   }
```

Colon `:` ---> `or` hello `or` world

Look here: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/Xjoqwm?editors=0010

Documentation react rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

if `variable` is `true` return `<p> hello </ p>` if `false` return `<p> world </ p>`

Comment: But what is I have a colon within the text, like `<p> hel:lo </p>`

Comment: `:`  ---> `or`   hello or world

Comment: What do you mean? How would I use that in this scenario: `<p style="color:black"> hello </p>`... as you can see, the colon in `color:black` needs to be escaped...?

Comment: colon  `:`  is between paragraphs

Comment: Yes I know, *but* I want to add an inline styling, [like this](https://pastebin.com/wa95wbyM). Do you see the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195057/discussion-between-umbro-and-henrik-petterson).

Comment: <p style={{ color: 'black'}}>hello</p>

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It acts the same as an if/else statement, where `?` is the if, and `:` is the else:

```js
condition
  ? // code where condition is true
  : // code where condition is false
```

Here's how you would implement it:

```html
return (
   <>
     <p title='name'> TEST </p>
     {variable ? <p> hello </p> : <p> world </p>}
   </>
)
```

> Note, I noticed you used `title={'name'}`. This works fine, but you can write it as normal html: `title='name'`. Also, react components only take one child component when rendering, so you can wrap your returned nodes in a React fragment or just a div.

Comment: But what is I have a colon within the text, like `<p> hel:lo </p>`. Do I need to escape it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional rendering within react. Read more on this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

In your case, a ternary operator would work well. The syntax of which is as follows:

`condition ? if : else`

In your case you could use it like this:

```
return (
   <p title={ 'name' }> TEST </p>
  {variable ?
      <p> hello </p>
   :
      <p> world </p>
   }
)
```

Comment: But what is I have a colon within the text, like `<p> hel:lo </p>`. Do I need to escape it?

Comment: Having a colon in the text wouldn't make a difference because its inside the <p> tag :)